# Can't detect/use external monitor on HP Pavilion DV5

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, graphics, external-monitor

I've just installed **Ubuntu 12.04 LTS** on a **HP Pavilion DV5** laptop that was previously with Ubuntu 11.04.

The installation was not an upgrade, was a fresh install to clean up the hard-drive with an erase and wipe tool.

When running the Live CD, and testing Ubuntu prior to the installation, all was OK, the desktop was present both on LCD and external monitor. But after the installation, the external monitor does not show any image.

**The relevant specifications:**

- HP Pavilion DV5-1160
- NVIDIA GeForce 9200M GS - 256 MB

Any idea on how to solve this issue or install some application that might help identify the problem?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of thoughts:

1. Have you tried detecting the app with the ATI settings application?
2. If you go into the system settings and click on Displays does it detect the other screen? I had to click detect displays to have the system see the other monitor.

Comment: Sorry for the delay for the feed back, was not a pertinent issue and I haven't dealt with it till now! I've updated the answer with the relevant specifications. (it is an nvidia chipset)